# how to kill a process running on remote windows machine from linux?

Tags: linux, remote, kill, maemo, windows

I am looking for something like 
[SysInternals pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) which is just great!

But that can be executed on Linux more exactly I want it to run on Maemo (Nokia N900 phone). Please do not offer me to run a Wine or any other windows emulation environment.

Of course I got the credentials for the Windows machine and windows machine is general Windows XP or Windows 7 not Windows Server.

Comment: This does not sound like a programming-related question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PSKILL tool does what it does by:

- Copy the file to the target machine
- Using WMI to create a service on the target machine that launches the file copied
- Starts the service on the remote machine
- Removes the service on the target machine
- Removes the file from the target machine

Samba, and by extension Linux, can do the first and last bullet-points. The others are currently not possible. Such a tool does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! This is clear and educational. But let me rephrase the question. Can it be any done at all in any way? I do not care how :-)

Comment: @BorisDaich The short-version: 1) install Cygwin to the target, 2) SSH in, 3) pskill it from there. Alternately, use rdesktop to connect to target, pskill it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late:

Well it is possible if you have installed sysinternals/microsoft PSkill on your server.
and you have a user on your server that has the rights to run rpc commands.

from your linux run the following commands:

```
net rpc service create killproc killproc "%windir%\pskill <program name|process id>" -I <server ip> -U <username>%<password>

net rpc service start killproc -I <server ip> -U <username>%<password>

net rpc service delete killproc -I <server ip> -U <username>%<password>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WinEXE](http://winexe.sourceforge.net/). I'm not sure if it will compile correctly on an N900, but it will allow you to run command to run "process -k whatever" remotely.